# Proof of this simple inequality: $\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{d} + \frac{d}{a} \geq 4$

Tags: inequality, contest-math, substitution, a.m.-g.m.-inequality, sum-of-squares-method

Let $a, b, c, d \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}$, then prove that

$\frac{a}{b} + \frac{b}{c} + \frac{c}{d} + \frac{d}{a} \geq 4$

Can this be done without using AM-GM inequality, or without using *any* identity/theorem of inequality? I don't want it to be concise or elegant, I just want rigorous steps that show explicitly how we achieve that result.

Thanks in advance

Comment: By identity, do you also not want to include $x^2 \geq 0$? You can do it via calculus.

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг I mean, anything that is obvious or easily deductible can be used, but not something that has a separate proof to itself. You get what I'm saying?

Comment: Yes, I understand.

Comment: @RobArthan great catch! I've edited it. Thanks!

Comment: @Mihir Chaturvedi without math you can not solve a math's problem. Can I use $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$?

Comment: A relevant post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/686791/prove-that-dfracab-dfracbc-dfraccd-dfracda-ge-4-where-we

ref: https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7Ba%7D%7Bb%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7Bb%7D%7Bc%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7Bc%7D%7Bd%7D%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%7Bd%7D%7Ba%7D%20%5Cgeq%204%24&p=1

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg anything that is obvious or easily deductible can be used, but not something that has a separate proof to itself.

Comment: @user170039 that's brilliant and simple! It's the kind of proof I wanted. Why don't you post it as an answer? Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can also do the proof in the following manner. $$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}\ge 2\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{c}}$$$$\dfrac{c}{d}+\dfrac{d}{a}\ge 2\sqrt{\dfrac{c}{a}}$$So, $$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{d}+\dfrac{d}{a}\ge 2\left(\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{c}}+\sqrt{\dfrac{c}{a}}\right)\ge 2\left(2\sqrt{\sqrt{\dfrac{a}{c}}\cdot\sqrt{\dfrac{c}{a}}}\right)=4 $$

Answer (score 5):

Let $\frac{a}{b}=x^4$, $\frac{b}{c}=y^4$, $\frac{c}{d}=z^4$ and $\frac{d}{a}=t^4$ for positives $x$, $y$, $z$ and $t$.

Hence, we need to prove that $x^4+y^4+z^4+t^4\geq4xyzt$, which is true because
$$x^4+y^4+z^4+t^4-4xyzt=(x^2-y^2)^2+(z^2-t^2)^2+2(xy-zt)^2\geq0$$

Comment: Could you please elaborate on how you got $$(x^2-y^2)^2+(z^2-t^2)^2+2(xy-zt)^2\geq0$$

Comment: @MihirChaturvedi: The expression is a sum of four squares, hence non-negative.