# Prove that :$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}\geq4$

Tags: inequality, contest-math

I found this problem in an old textbook of mine and couldn't solve it:
***Prove The following:***
$$\frac{a}{b}+\frac{b}{c}+\frac{c}{d}+\frac{d}{a}\geq4$$

$$a,b,c,d>0$$

This problem was from a mathematical olympiad related book and to my knowledge math olympiads use a lot of identities and tricks which are known by contestants

-If anyone can help prove it, I would be grateful

Comment: AM GM inequality

Comment: You can (as a learning experience) do this as a minimization problem using Lagrange multipliers.

Comment: This has been asked and answered several times: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1956583, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/686791, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1921395 – found with [Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%20ab%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%20bc%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%20cd%20%2B%20%5Cfrac%20da%20%5Cge%204%24)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Lower bound for cyclic expression in four variables](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1956583/lower-bound-for-cyclic-expression-in-four-variables)

Answer (score 3):

Just apply $AM \ge GM$ on $\frac{a}{b} , \frac{b}{c},\frac{c}{d},\frac{d}{a}$

Answer (score 2):

By AM. GM We have $$\dfrac{a}{b}+\dfrac{b}{c}+\dfrac{c}{d}+\dfrac{d}{a}\ge 4\sqrt[4]{\dfrac{a}{b}\cdot \dfrac{b}{c} \cdot \dfrac{c}{d}\cdot \dfrac{d}{a}}=4$$